# Mounting filesystem in unprivileged container

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, containers, linux-device-driver

I am exploring Linux kernel. While studying I found that In super_block structure new field s_user_ns is added. I understand that this field is added to keep the kuid and kgid of new user namespace which will help in mount and other filesystem operations.

To mount filesystem in user namespace or in unprivileged container we can use bind mount. So my question is that what is use case of mounting filesystem in user namespace or in unprivileged container using s_user_ns ?